# App name changes in recent tasks

Tags: java, android, activity-lifecycle

I'm currently having a problem with my app. Let's say my app name is `TestApp`, but when I pass the login activity (which is the launcher activity of my app), the app name in the recent apps taskbar changes to "main menu" (which is the activity I go after logging in).

My best guest right now is the flags I'm using in my intent to start the activity:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

If this is the problem, is there any other method to start and activity finishing all the others?

Comment: Post your manifest file please. The reason is not in Intent flags you're using but in names you applied in your application/activity/intent-filter declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The name of android:label tag is set as the header of the recent activity.